# Qt - Symbian Mobile - Soft key menus not displaying correctly

Tags: qt, mobile, qt4, symbian, nokia

[image]

I create and show a QWebView with soft key options at the bottom.  When I click "Options", a menu shows up, but it's tiny, black, and in the upper left hand corner (it should look like the standard blue soft keys and be directly above them). I followed this [example](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_add_submenu_in_Qt_for_Symbian).

```
//create webview
webView = new QWebView;
webView->setUrl(QString(":html/internal.html"));

//create menu
QAction *option1 = new QAction(tr("Back"), webView);
option1->setSoftKeyRole(QAction::PositiveSoftKey);
    connect(option1, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(deleteView()));

//create right softkey action to launch the "options" menu
QAction *option2 = new QAction(tr("Options"), webView);
option2->setSoftKeyRole(QAction::NegativeSoftKey);
    connect(option2, SIGNAL(triggered(), this, SLOT(showMenu()));

QMenu *menuOptions = new QMenu(webView);
menuOptions->addAction(tr("Sub Menu 1"), this, SLOT(aboutView()));
menuOptions->addAction(tr("Sub Menu 2"), this, SLOT(aboutView()));
option2->setMenu(menuOptions);

//add softkey menus
QList < QAction* > softKeys;
softKeys.append(option1);
softKeys.append(option2);

webView->addActions(softKeys);
webView->show();
```

Comment: " If you're running this in Simulator, I'd suggest to give it a spin in a real hardware. Simulator might have some issues showing Symbian native components, such as Options menu ", so I'm going to give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://qt.gitorious.org/+qt-s60-developers/qt/qt-s60/trees/829307fa214586d40ff13d9e9eb4ece4d1bd4ff1/examples/widgets/softkeys) works well on simulator and also in phone. It is included in the QTDIR/examples/widgets folder since Qt 4.6.x